# Issue with pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

In this code, relied on `gdb`, `p` changes from `0x602010` to `0x0`  when `NULL` is assigned,  (as I would expect)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;

                        // gdb output
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));   // p = (int *) 0x602010
    p = NULL;               // p = (int *) 0x0
    p = &a;                 // p = p = (int *) 0x7fffffffe15c           

    return 0;
}
```

But, when `p` is changed outside of `main()` in `task()`, I guess it does not change to `0x0` and I don't why:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void tast(int *p);

void task(int *p)
{

/*
 before
 (gdb) p p
 $1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe15c         (same as variable a)
 (gdb) p &p
 $2 = (int **) 0x7fffffffe128
*/

    p = NULL;

/*
 after
 (gdb) p p
 $3 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe15c        no change?
 (gdb) p &p
 $4 = (int **) 0x7fffffffe128
*/    
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;

                        // gdb output
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));   // p = (int *) 0x602010
    p = NULL;               // p = (int *) 0x0
    p = &a;                 // p = p = (int *) 0x7fffffffe15c

    // it is possible to change what p points to 
    // after calling task()?
    task(p);

    // p will be NULL?          

    return 0;
}
```

Why p does not change to 0x0 inside task()?

Comment: Was there some code you wanted us to review?

Comment: Hint: pointers are passed by value.  If you changed an `int` in `task` would you expect the change to propagate?  You'll need to pass a pointer to a pointer if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: If `p` is not changed inside task() the compiler may have optimized away any changes to the value.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a value, like an `int`. Think of it like this: if you passed an `int` into `task()` and changed it inside the `task` function would expect it to change? No, because variables are passed by value.

When you call `task` you are passing a copy of the value (which, in this case, is a pointer) to the function. What you want to do is change the value of the pointer, which means you need a pointer to the location where the value is stored. This is a pointer to a pointer, `int **`.

instead:

```
void task(int **p)
{
   *p = NULL;
}
```

and

```
task(&p);
```

to pass the *location* of `p *`.

Another example, this time using `int`, which may make it clearer.

```
void makeTen(int *valuePointer)
{
    // Change the variable that valuePointer is pointing to. 
    *valuePointer = 10; 
}

void demoFunction()
{
    int x = 5;

    // x == 5

    // Call this with a pointer to the variable X.
    // We are passing the memory address of the variable x.
    makeTen(&x);

    // x == 10

}
```

If you understand this, change `int` to be `int *` and you will understand your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st snippet, you are leaking memory as you assign NULL to a malloc'ed pointer.

In the 2nd snippet, you are passing the pointer by its value. So the changes won't reflect in main. [This explains the problem.](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `p == NULL` in main after passing the pointer, you will need to pass a pointer to the pointer. For instance

```
void task(int** p)
{
  *p = NULL;
}
```

and pass

```
task(&p);
```

Also, you should note that this code leaks. You should `free(p)` before setting `p = NULL` after the `malloc` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are mistaking the pointer address and the object it points to.

```
void task(int *p)
{
    p = NULL; 
}
```

This function will take a pointer to int, thus, you are allowed to modify the int value that is stored somewhere else. The address of the variable for your int value is passed by value though. That means, the address is stored locally. Assigning 'NuLL' to a local variable is not what you want.

If you change it to this:

```
void task(int **p)
{
    *p = NULL; 
}
```

You will take a pointer to a pointer to int. Now the address is also pointed to and you can change it from your code. A pointer to int will have to be passed by reference (which is your case).